# Is is possible to detect focus lost on a jSpinner's buttons

Tags: java, swing, jspinner

I am using a `JSpinner` to adjust values on a graph, which has an undo function. I don't want to create an undo for each spinner button click event, but rather a single undo when the user has finished clicking the `JSpinner` buttons and has moved the mouse away from the spinner control.

The normal `JSpinner` `mouseExited` is very flaky if the user moves the mouse pointer away too quickly (moving it slowly works if the mouse pointer is detected on the border between the spinner buttons and the `JSpinner` border). Is it possible to detect mouseExited for the spinner buttons themselves? 'FocusLost' does not enable the undo button if it is the first undo until the user clicks elsewhere and they may assume that their changes cannot be undone if they don't.

Any alternative ways of doing this would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can use a `MouseListener` and handle `mouseEntered` and `mouseExited`.

What happens with the undo logic if the user uses the keyboard to increase/decrease the spinner value?

Maybe a better solution is to listen for a value change and then start a `Timer` to fire in 1 or 2 seconds. When the Timer fires you do you processing. Every time the value changes you reset the Timer. These will you will group all changes made within you defined interval. This solution would also work whether the uses the mouse or the keyboard.

Comment: Sorry camickr, it was mouseExited that I was using, not focusLost. I tried focus lost some time ago but if it was the first undo then the undo button would not un-ghost until they clicked elsewhere, and the user might assume that they could not undo the changes they had just made if they didn't. I like your idea of the timer though, nice and simple; thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was testing for `MouseInputListener` and `MouseAdapter`.

```
JSpinner.DefaultEditor jspdeSpinner = (JSpinner.DefaultEditor)theSpinner.getEditor();

MouseListener ml_milForSpin = new MouseInputListener() {
  @Override
  public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) { }
  @Override
  public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) { }
  @Override
  public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) { }
  @Override
  public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) { }
  @Override
  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) { }
  @Override
  public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println(" - > mouseEntered(x:" + e.getX() + " , y:"+ e.getY() + ")");
  }
  @Override
  public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println(" - > mouseExited(x:" + e.getX() + " , y:"+ e.getY() + ")");
  }
};
MouseListener ml_maForSpin = new MouseAdapter() {
  @Override
  public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) { }
  @Override
  public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) { }
  @Override
  public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) { }
  @Override
  public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) { }
  @Override
  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) { }
  @Override
  public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println(" - > mouseEntered(x:" + e.getX() + " , y:"+ e.getY() + ")");
  }
  @Override
  public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println(" - > mouseExited(x:" + e.getX() + " , y:"+ e.getY() + ")");
  }
};
```

Testing Assigned The Listener

```
jspdeSpinner.addMouseListener(ml_maForSpin);  // Doesn't Work!!!
jspdeSpinner.addMouseListener(ml_milForSpin);  // Doesn't Work!!!
```

//Checking this

```
JTextField jtfSpinner = jspdeSpinner.getTextField();

jtfSpinner.addMouseListener(ml_maFragment);  //Work!
jtfSpinner.addMouseListener(ml_milFragment);  //Work!
```

If you need to change something of `SpinnerModel`, Don't create a new, change its parameters instead! (if you do it, you will need to reassign the MouseListener again, because it will be lost when you assign a new SpinnerModel).

an example (I'm talking...):

```
((SpinnerNumberModel)theSpinner.getModel()).setValue(size/3);
((SpinnerNumberModel)theSpinner.getModel()).setMinimum(0);
((SpinnerNumberModel)theSpinner.getModel()).setMaximum(isize/2);
((SpinnerNumberModel)theSpinner.getModel()).setStepSize(1);
```